# How to configure PHP apc so that caching is done automatically?

Tags: php, apc

When we `include($file)` ,caching is done internally,automatically.

How to achieve that?

Comment: What kind of caching? Opcode? User-cache entries? Opcode caching should already be on by default.

Comment: You should do some benchmarking to see if APC is working correctly. 

If you have ssh access to the server you can use apache bench:
ab -c 10 -n 1000 http://yoursite.com/

Test before and after installing apc. You should see about a 3x increase in requests per second.

Comment: By default we need to call `apc_store()` **explicitly**, I'm asking about the **implicit** way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is nonsensical when combined with your comment.  Caching of bytecode and being able to cache a variable value are two entirely unrelated things.

`apc_store` is used to store a variable in the shared cache.  It has nothing to do with file includes.

APC *also* caches PHP bytecode.  It does so automatically unless [the `apc.cache_by_default` configuration directive](http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.cache-by-default) is turned off and filters are used as described on the manual page.

You can see if APC is enabled in general by checking the value of [the `apc.enabled` configuration directive](http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.enabled).

You can not have APC automatically cache a variable.

Comment: Why do you say caching `bytecode` and `variable` are entirely unrelated?

Comment: Bytecode caching is not the same thing as variable caching.  They are different things done in different ways for different reasons.  Maybe I don't understand what you're asking, can you ask it in a different way?